# Condición en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un código que se encarga de comparar la el valor de una fecha guardada en una base de datos con la fecha actual.

```
//Variable que toma la fecha de la BD
$postDate = new DateTime($row["post_datetime"]);
//Fecha actual
$actualDate = new DateTime();
//Se comparan fechas
$interval = $postDate->diff($actualDate);
```

Al insertar la variable en el documento:

```
//Se muestra la comparación
$interval->format('%Y years %m months %d days %H hours %i minutes %s seconds');
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer una condición para tomar %s o %i dentro de $interval?

¿Se puede hacer 
      `if ( $interval [%s] )`  ?

Comment: No se entiende lo que preguntas: *`¿Cómo puedo hacer una condición que tome por ejemplo tomando %s o cualquiera?`*

Comment: No se entiende muy bien la pregunta, la puedes editar?

Comment: Pregunta editada.

Comment: usa `$interval->format( ( )?( ):( ) );`, se le entiendes es tu solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacer un:

```
// formato que deseas
$date_format = ["Y","m","d","H","i","s"];
//creamos array de objeto
$d=  array();
//$row["post_datetime"]="2018-03-02 02:24:34";
// loop para formatear
foreach ($date_format as $df) {
  // de df obtenemos su segundo valor que seria Ymdhis ya que el o es %
  // agregamos a el objeto $d["Y"] = "2019"; solo el a;o y asi sucesivamente con todos
  $d[$df]=date($df, strtotime($row["post_datetime"]));
}
// imprimimos el objeto
// o comparamos ya usted decide
print_r($d);
```

el laravel seria:

```
   // formato que deseas
$date_format = ["Y","m","d","H","i","s"];
//creamos array de objeto
$d=  array();
//$row["post_datetime"]="2018-03-02 02:24:34";
// loop para formatear
foreach ($date_format as $df) {
  // de df obtenemos su segundo valor que seria Ymdhis ya que el o es %
  // agregamos a el objeto $d["Y"] = "2019"; solo el a;o y asi sucesivamente con todos
 $d[$df]=$row["post_datetime"]->format($df);
}
// imprimimos el objeto
// o comparamos ya usted decide
print_r($d);
```

si deseas puedes validar de forma directa:

```
if($row["post_datetime"]->format("Y") == "2019"){
  echo "yes el a;o es 2019";
}

if(date("Y", strtotime($row["post_datetime"])); == "2019"){
  echo "yes el a;o es 2019";
}
```

Comment: Hice tal cual lo que me dijiste y me salta:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"%s"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING),

Comment: sorry lo escribi directo y no lo probe! ya ahora si esta bien!